# How to pass variables form JavaScript file to tailwind.config file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using `tailwind css` for first time in my project. I know how to use `tailwind-config` to make variables for `colors', 'border-radius' etc.

but In this scenario,

The `background-color`, `color` etc. will come through `api` so the `response` is set into a `state` variable.

Now I actually need to add the value of `state` variable into in `tailwind-config` so that the variable for `background-color`, `color` etc in `tailwind-config` gets its value and due to that every element using it changes accordingly.

Comment: I think this is not possible in your case (where response color could be anything). Well you may pass variable but at the end you need to compile your styles. It will work in watch mode but not in production. Even if you pass new variable into config, old color value will be loaded from CSS file for specific class name unless you recompile your styles again. However if your response is a list of predefined colors you may safelist it. Otherwise I recommend to use inline styles or CSS vairables - again it depends how often these colors will be re-used

Comment: The thing is when the value of state will change the components will re-render themselves so the styles will also recompile with new color. I can obviously go for inline styles defining a variable in my JavaScript file (but that's last option). I have already made variables in `tailwind-config` and I am using them on temporary basis now

Comment: What I mean: If you defined your color as green in config, it will be rendered in CSS as green. If you change your variable into red, Tailwind will NOT recompile itself and its styles, so the value of `green` will remain `green` even if your variable now is `red`. Simulate state changing variable value with `.env` file in production mode (not watch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved now after doing some R&D and after changing the perspective.

Here is the explanation
The scenario:

1. Colors are coming from API response.
2. I want them to fit in `tailwind.config.js` so that the variables can later be used in various places in project.

So the changes basically lies in 2 files of the project

- `tailwind.config.js`
- `app.js`(or wherever you make an API call)

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
    darkMode: "class",
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: "var(--bg-nav)",
                secondary: "var(--bg-color)",
            },
        },
    },
};
```

The `primary` and `secondary` colors are coming from our `app.js` file, the syntax is same as we use in `CSS`

**App.js**

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {

useEffect( () => {
    //make an API call and set the response data to a variable
    const brandColor = "#0ff0f0";
    const bgColor = "#a5cd3e";
}, [])

    return (
        <section>
            <style
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: ` :root {
                             --bg-nav: ${brandColor};
                             --bg-color: ${bgColor}
                           }`,
                    }}
            />  
        </section>
    );
};
```

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

This will make things work as expected.

However there are no changes in `index.css` just to cross check here is index.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import "./fonts/stylesheet.css";

@layer base {

    ul,
    ol {
        list-style: revert;
    }
}

body {
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```